# Sqlalchemy One-to-Many Insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a dictionary and a list (of dictionaries) variables that I parsed some data into and these two variables have one-to-many relation between each other. I wonder if there is any way to put these dictionaries into table classes and store them into the database. I expect sqlalchemy to handle the foreign key details. Also Dictionaries have lots of keys so it should populate the object fields from dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps involved in [creating a Many To One relationship in SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#many-to-one):

1. [Create the constraint on the `Dependent` object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#defining-foreign-keys). This will ensure that `Dependent`s only reference valid `Master`s. For this, you will need a [Primary Key](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/schema.html) on the `Master` object.
2. [Create a reference](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one) so you can access the `Master` in an Object-Oriented fashion from the `Dependent`.

---

A note: don't get confused. The SQLAlchemy documentation uses an example where the relationship is Parents (n) -> Child (1). To avoid confusion, I used the wording Dependent (n) -> Master (1).

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I figured it out. I created two table objects and corresponding two empty classes. Using mapper, mapped the classes to the tables. However I still need to figure out this dictionary to class passing. Is there a way to pass from dictionary to the class where the keys are fields?

Comment: def __init__(self, **entries): self.__dict__.update(entries) did the job.

Comment: interesting idea with dependent->master, my thinking has always been "parent to child == left to right" on this.   but I should consider modernizing that.

Comment: @zzzeek I borrowed this thinking to salesforce.com; I think it's better than parent / child to represent Foreign Keys, as Parent ~ Children is more of a Many to Many relationship!